# 2つの3次元実数値ベクトルxとyが与えられた時、xからyへ回転する行列を求めたい

Tags: python

2つの長さが同じ3次元実数値ベクトル（空間上の位置）xとyが与えられた時、
xからy（あるいはyからx）へ回転する行列Rを求めたいです。
numpyやscipyを使って、どのようなコードでこれを実現できるでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

まず、Mathematics Stack Exchange 上の[同様の質問](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/180418/371701)に対する [Nico Schlömer](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/36678/nico-schl%C3%B6mer) さんの[回答](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2672702/371701)を和訳します：

> [ロドリゲスの回転公式](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula)を使うと、ベクトル `a` を回転軸 `k` まわりに角 `θ` だけ回転したときのベクトルが得られます。ここで単位ベクトル `a` を `b` に回転するには `a` を `(a + b) / 2` まわりに `π` だけ回転すれば良いことを考えると、この公式から以下の美しい式を得ます：
>
> [image: R = 2 * (a+b)(a+b)^T / ((a+b)^T (a+b)) - I]

この式は `a`, `b` が単位ベクトルのときに限らず、`a` と `b` の長さが等しく `a ≠ -b` であれば使えます。このことから、上の式をそのまま実装してみました。

```py
import numpy as np

def rotation_matrix_3d(frm, to):
    if np.array_equal(frm, to):
        return np.identity(3)
    if np.array_equal(frm, -to):
        return -np.identity(3)

    s = frm + to
    return 2.0 * np.outer(s, s) / np.dot(s, s) - np.identity(3)
```

以下は動作テストの様子です。

```py
def generate(r):
    theta = np.random.uniform(0, 2.0 * np.pi)
    cosphi = np.random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0)
    sinphi = np.sqrt(1.0 - cosphi * cosphi)
    v = r * np.array([np.cos(theta) * sinphi, np.sin(theta) * sinphi, cosphi])
    return v

if __name__ == '__main__':
    r = np.random.random()
    a = generate(r)
    b = generate(r)
    r = rotation_matrix_3d(a, b)

    # test
    print(" R =", r)
    print()
    print(" a =", a)
    print("Ra =", np.dot(r, a))
    print(" b =", b)
```

```sh
$ python test.py
 R = [[-0.33930792  0.7584119   0.55649036]
 [ 0.7584119  -0.129415    0.6387982 ]
 [ 0.55649036  0.6387982  -0.53127708]]

 a = [0.83254887 0.9255484  0.65935197]
Ra = [0.78637951 0.93282798 0.70424549]
 b = [0.78637951 0.93282798 0.70424549]
```

Comment: すごく簡潔な式になるのですね。びっくりしました。実装もありがとうございます。私の実現したいことがこれでできました。